# instagram Web scraping using python

Tags: python-3.x, api, instagram, instaloader

Is there any way to web scrape a usernames who like the post using python?. I am using InstaLoader but  Facing an error "LoginRequiredException: --login required to access likes of a post" .
Can anyone help me out in this?

```
import instaloader 
L = instaloader.Instaloader() 
Post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(L.context, 'CKplgftjVW_') 
for like in Post.get_likes(): 
    print(like.username)
```

Comment: Can you show us some code you already tried? Also please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your question so we can help you better

Comment: Yes . I am sharing code. @Hoargarth
import instaloader

L = instaloader.Instaloader()

Post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(L.context, 'CKplgftjVW_')

for like in Post.get_likes():
print(like.username)

Answer (score 0):

you can use your instagram account to test (you should be able to see the post using your instagram account means **you cannot see a private instagram account's posts**)

```
import instaloader 
L = instaloader.Instaloader() 
user = 'your_instagram_username'
password = 'your_instagram_password'

try:
    L.login(user,password)
   
    Post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(L.context, 'CKplgftjVW_') 
    for like in Post.get_likes(): 
         print(like.username)
except:
    print('Somthing went wrong')
```